# How to rerun the failed scenarios using parallel_tests?

Tags: cucumber

i have file rerun.txt in my project root directory =>

```
config/
features/
rerun.txt
```

rerun.txt =>

```
features/auth.feature:11
```

I try this:

```
bundle exec parallel_cucumber @rerun1.txt -o "ENV=.$env BROWSER=chrome" --group-by scenarios -n 2
```

=>

```
17:04:51 features/myroom/vacancy-add.feature:65:63:62:64/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:58:in `initialize': No such file or directory - @rerun1.txt. Please create a @rerun1.txt directory to get started. (Errno::ENOENT)
```

and this:

```
bundle exec parallel_cucumber features/ -o "ENV=.$env BROWSER=chrome @rerun1.txt" --group-by scenarios -n 2
```

but this execute all scenarios in features/ folder

Comment: i do this: `rerun=\`cat rerun1.txt\`; bundle exec parallel_cucumber $rerun -o "ENV=.$env BROWSER=chrome" --group-by scenarios -n 2` and it's work

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this before, but I believe the `@` symbol you've added to the  command line is the culprit. Try:

```
bundle exec parallel_cucumber ./rerun1.txt -o "ENV=.$env BROWSER=chrome" --group-by scenarios -n 2
```

Comment: Try this just to make sure it's nothing else:

bundle exec parallel_cucumber features/auth.feature:11 -o "ENV=.$env BROWSER=chrome" --group-by scenarios -n 2

Comment: it's work fine. and i do this: `rerun=\`cat rerun1.txt\`; bundle exec parallel_cucumber $rerun -o "ENV=.$env BROWSER=chrome" --group-by scenarios -n 2` , work fine too